# Javacard Collections

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I have been looking through the JavaCard API and examples and could not find any reference to higher level data collections like List, ArrayList, HashMaps and the likes ?

Am I missing something ?

I am aware that JavaCard environments are very limited in resource and the JVM must be as tiny as possible but the lack of some form of easy to use data collection objects can make processes rather manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, there are no collections like List, ArrayList or HashMap in JavaCard API. Arrays are all you have - you can implement your own ArrayList if it is necessary. There is no String either, after all.

JavaCard is not Java, although the name can be confusing. Coding in JavaCard is very low-level. You should take JavaCard rather as the assembler with Java syntax.

Comment: That would mean if I want to manipulate a list of data objects, I have to somehow copy and move byte[] objects around.

Answer (score 1):

There is no collection in JCVM. In javacard, there is only byte/short array for you to use; additionally, 2-dimension(and above) array is also not supported.

you will have to design and implement your own data structure for complex data storage.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Collection / Hash Map / String / Mutithreading / 2D Array / Garbage Collection finalize() are **not** supported by Java Card architecture. In java card, there is only byte/short type of array available to use . Supported Data Types are 
boolean / Byte / Short / Integer(supported on some platforms)

Answer (score 0):

## Javacard is a very small subset of the Java it only support

Boolean, byte, short
Int keyword is optional
A one-dimensional array
Java packages
Classes and interfaces
abnormal
inheritance
polymorphism

## overloading

not support
Long, double, float, and all the wrapper classes
Char, String
Multidimensional array
Dynamic class loading
The safety management
Finilize method
thread
serialization
Clone method

Answer (score 0):

It depends which of java card api version you are using,
Up to java card 2.2.2, Higher level data collections are not available, but from java card 3.0(classic or connected) in both, you can use most of your higher level data collections.
you can find more detail on [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javacard/download/releasenotes-jsp-137685.html)